# Proof that the hyperbolae $x^2-y^2 =a$ and $xy=b$ are orthogonal via parametric equations

Tags: calculus, parametric

could anyone help me with this problem?

Prove that the hyperbolae $x^2-y^2 =a$ and $xy=b$ are orthogonal to each other at each point they intersect. Here $a$ and $b$ are non zero parameters.

I first did a parameterization
                          $$y=t$$  $$x=\frac{b}{t}$$

Then I differentiated both equations to get the unit tangent vector.
                                $$y'=1$$  $$x'=\frac{-b}{t^2}$$

From here onward I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Yup should be that

Comment: The strategy in general should be to show that $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ in the first equation has slope m and the second equation has slope $  \frac{-1}{m} $ ( I understand this is to be shown in parametric form)

Comment: My thinking is that it should be converted to a parametric equation , then differentiate it to find tangent vector, and from there do a cross product of the tangent vector to show that its zero to prove that it is orthogonal.

Comment: It's straight forward without parametric equations though.

Comment: perhaps the dot product of the equations will vanish in parametric form.

Answer (score 3):

Implicit derivatives will work nicely here. First we assume $b\neq 0$ or else the second hyperbola really is just the two axes (not a hyperbola). Then any point $(x,y)$ on both curves at once must have $x,y \neq 0.$ Implicit differentiation of $x^2-y^2=a$ gives $2x-2yy'=0,\ y'=x/y.$ on the other hand, implicit differentiation of $xy=b$ gives $xy'+y=0,\ y'=-y/x.$ Thus at any point on both hyperbolas, one slope is $x/y$ while the other is its negative reciprocal $-y/x$, showing the curves are orthogonal where they meet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for parametric equations. Take an arbitrary point $(x,y)$. By differentiating the implicit equations,

$$\begin{cases}x-yy_a'=0,\\ y+xy_b'=0\end{cases}$$

implies $$y_a'y_b'=-1.$$

---

If you really want parametric equations,

$$(x+y)(x-y)=a\iff x+y=t,x-y=\frac at\iff x=\frac12\left(t+\frac at\right),y=\frac12\left(t-\frac at\right).$$

$$xy=b\iff x=u,y=\frac bu.$$

The tangent vectors are proportional to

$$\frac12\left(1-\frac a{t^2},1+\frac a{t^2}\right)=\frac1t(y,x)$$

and

$$\left(1,-\frac b{u^2}\right)=\frac1u(x,-y).$$

Obviously, the dot product is null.